# How to store location data from GPS in sqlite using AsyncTask?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, gps, android-sqlite

I tried to use the storage class AsyncTask location information through GPS sqlite but not how. I need help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, unfortunately your question does not demonstrate any attempt of prior research. In order to get a good response, it is advised you should show evidence you have attempted to solve the problem, either in code or otherwise, before asking a question. 

StackOverflow is not a free code generator. Please seek assistance elsewhere should you require free source code.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Async Task has a way to communicate with sqlite?
You can communicate between threads/apps with intents, You can also notify things to threads in your code with the async task.
Can you show me your code?